# Babel fails to hyphenate when the word contains periods

Tags: babel, hyphenation

[`babel`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel) can hyphenate `disputas`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nynorsk]{babel}
\begin{document}
\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}disputas}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But it fails when the word contains a period:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nynorsk]{babel}
\begin{document}
\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}Dr.-disputas}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why, and how can I fix it?

Comment: The period, in this case, is completely irrelevant. Words containing an explicit hyphen are only possibly broken at the hyphen. Use `"-` instead of `-`

Comment: @egreg If the period is completely irrelvant, then why can't `babel` hyphenate `Dr.disputas` at all?

Comment: The case of `Dr.disputas` is completely different.

Comment: @egreg Well, maybe, but then you see why I would think it was the period that prevented the hyphenation.

Comment: @egreg So there's no way to hyphenate `Dr.-disputas`? I tried `\babelhyphenation{Dr.-dis-pu-tas}`, but that throws an error. I can easily imagine a German word like `un-<really long German compound word>`, and I'd hate to think that `babel` has no way of hyphenating the compound.

Comment: We german would input the hyphen as `"=` in such cases.

Comment: If you are using pdfTeX with the T1 font encoding, for the case of an explicit hyphen, you could use the *other* hyphen character, which avoids blocking hyphenation in the remainder of the word. However, this obviously won't work for the case of a full stop.

Answer (score 3):

The cases of `Dr.-disputas` and `Dr.disputas` are completely different. An explicit hyphen makes TeX break the chunk only at it, ignoring hyphenation patterns in the rest of the word parts.

With `babel` for Norsk or Nynorsk you can use `"-` that allows hyphenation past the hyphen.

When `Dr.disputas` is considered, the general rule for hyphenation enters: it is explained on page 254 of the TeXbook, second doubly dangerous paragraph.

> TeX looks for potentially hyphenatable words by searching ahead from each glue item that is not in a math formula. The search bypasses charac- ters whose `\lccode` is zero, or ligatures that begin with such characters; it also bypasses whatsits and *implicit kern* items, i.e., kerns that were inserted by TeX itself because of information stored with the font. If the search finds a character with nonzero `\lccode`, or if it finds a ligature that begins with such a character, that character is called the *starting letter*. But if any other type of item occurs before a suitable starting letter is found, hyphenation is abandoned (until after the next glue item).

So `D` is the *starting letter* and hyphenation is tried on `Dr`, because the zero `\lccode` of the period ends the trial word; of course `Dr` can't be hyphened. There's no glue, so `.disputas` is not good for hyphenation. Indeed,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nynorsk]{babel}

\begin{document}

\parbox{0pt}{
  \hspace{0pt}disputas.disputas
}

\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

You can use the shorthand `""` in this case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nynorsk]{babel}

\begin{document}

\parbox{0pt}{
  \hspace{0pt}disputas.""disputas
}

\end{document}
```

will give

[image]

Comment: As I just pointed out in my comment to Ulrike's answer, this won't work for me now because the word that I need hyphenated is in my `.bib` file, and if I put in codes like `"-` or `"=`, `biber` throws an error. Should I open a separate question about this (if there is a solution)?

Comment: @Sverre Yes, this is indeed a different problem.

Comment: @Sverre `babel` also has `\babelhyphen{empty}` as explizit form for `""`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to allow hyphenation in a word which already has a hyphen you can use in your language (as I can do it in german) `"=`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nynorsk]{babel}

\begin{document}
\parbox{0pt}{Dr."=disputas}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What's with the extra blank line?

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, because my word `Dr.-disputas` is in my `.bib` file. Putting `"=` there results in `syntax error: found "=", expected end of entry ("}" or ")")` when I run `biber`.

Comment: @Sverre instead of the shorthand `"=` you can also use `babel`'s explizit macro: `Dr.\babelhyphen{hard}disputas`.

Comment: In bib-files you can use the biblatex command `\hyphen`, see the documentation of biblatex. And the blank like is because of the 0pt-box.

Comment: Ok, both `\babelhyphen{hard}` and `\biblatex`'s `\hyphen` seem to do what I want. Any reason to prefer one over the other?

Comment: In  a  bib I would always use the biblatex commands (unless the bib is needed for bibtex too, but even then one could add fallback definitions.).

Answer (score 1):

If using LuaLaTeX is an option for you, you may give the following code a try:

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nynorsk]{babel}
\begin{document}
\parbox{0pt}{Dr.-\hspace{0pt}disputas}
\end{document}
```

Note that Lua(La)TeX doesn't possess the well-known problem of pdf(La)TeX and Xe(La)TeX of not being able to hyphenate the first word of a paragraph.