# Software Documentation Dot-Operator/Period Hyphenation

Tags: packages, hyphenation, package-writing

I'm still new-ish to latex, and I'm trying to document some software using the tool. I'm referencing local terms that are long and contain periods/dot-operators. I know how/why Latex doesn't like to hyphenate words with periods from this question:

[Babel fails to hyphenate when the word contains periods](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264018/babel-fails-to-hyphenate-when-the-word-contains-periods/264022#264022)

I found the post to not be so helpful. All these double quotes shortcuts don't make sense with the number of times I'm using these terms.

My understanding so far with Latex leads me to believe that this should be easily accomplished with some soft of function in the header (or editing hyphenation source) where if there is no space after a period make that word "hyphenable" after said period.

ORR... it would be even more awesome if there was a package that did this that i just haven't heard about yet.

Any help on this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an example of something you'd like to hyphenate?

Comment: @samcarter a suitable example may be IN_CAN0.SA0xGG.TeamProprietaryMsg.FeatureStatus_SubFeature

They are quite long, but very precise. Which what was asked of me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to treat such terms as verbatim material. You can allow linebreaks e.g. with the `listings` package and  `\lstinline[breaklines=true]`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

test test test test test test test test test test test test \lstinline[breaklines=true]|IN_CAN0.SA0xGG.TeamProprietaryMsg.FeatureStatus_SubFeature|

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to work pretty awesome. It's a little impractical to keep writing this out in the text considering how many times these items are referenced. But, I decided to add it in a variable definition at the start of the document. This ended up helping on multiple fronts. Now, i have a variable with a shorter name that I can write by reference. Also, because it's by reference if the signal name ever changes I only need to edit the definition... something I should have been doing before anyway with the # of occurrences I'm dealing with and potential volatility in its name. You rock! Thanks!

Comment: @CharlieBrown You're welcome!